# How to extend Cordova/Ionic Project by Apple Watch

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-watch

I am asking myself how to extend an existing Cordova/Ionic Project by an Apple Watch target, keeping in mind that:

- iOS related project files are generated
- extending the Xcode Project works well so far, but after Cordova base project update I am running out of sync: If I replace the newly generated project files with my AppleWatch extended ones I run into multiple errors during linking.

Also updating by adding/removing plugins on command line does not solve it for me (iOS build process got corrupted). Think that I have to remove and add the iOS platform again but how to add the existing WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension?
Only option I see is to restart and add the WatchKit again which is quite frustrating, do you have any advice for me?
It is possible to split up the iOS project file to plugin the Apple Watch target?

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered, you can remove and restore your watchkit by simply removing and restoring its directories. I managed this with the Time Machine, but git should have the same result.

1) Backup your entire project

2) Remove the /platforms/ios/ watchkit and watchkit extension directories

3) In the package contents of your .xcodeproj/xcschemes/ remove the watchkit app scheme(s)

You can now go back and remove and re-add your ios platform in cordova, add plugins, whatever you were unable to do, and platform build ios from the command line.

Add back the directories you removed and rebuild.

Obviously, I'd only recommend this in extreme circumstances, but I was forced into it and was pleasantly surprised when I had my new build of the cordova app and my old watchkit app restored alongside.

Xcode 10.1 running on Mojave 10.14.2